# jQuery Masonry append overlapping with infinite scroll

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have this script that allows the infinite scrolling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function last_id_funtion() {
            var ID = $(".elemento:last").attr("id");
            $.post("2HB.php?action=get&id=" + ID,
                    function(data) {
                        if (data != "") {
                            var $boxes = $(data);
                            //$(".elemento:last").after(data);
                            $("#corpo").append($boxes).masonry('appended', $boxes, 'reloadItems');

                        }
                    });
        };

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                last_id_funtion();
            }
        });
```

It is based on 2 queries, one for the first 10 results and another for the rest.
The problem is that Masonry overlaps the images until a page refresh is done... When the images are stored in the cache, it works perfectly, but not otherwise... 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `masonry('reload')`?

Comment: Yes, I have... Firebug says "no such method 'reload' for masonry instance" :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your masonry call in .imagesLoaded()

```
$("#corpo").imagesLoaded(function(){
  $("#corpo").append($boxes).masonry('appended', $boxes, 'reloadItems');
});
```

EDIT

According to the [Masonry Appendix](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html) *"imagesLoaded works by triggering a callback after all child images have been loaded."*. So if you run you trigger Masonry inside this callback everything it needs to do it's thing should be already loaded.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! :D
It so happens that I was trying to do that now, but the syntax was all wrong :p

Comment: You're welcome. I had that problem before when combining Masonry and InfiniteScroll.

Comment: What does 'appended' mean in the context of the masonry method?